# Some weird problem with Nokogiri's xpath method

Tags: html, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

```
doc.xpath('//img') #this will get some results
doc.xpath('//img[@class="productImage"]') #and this gets nothing at all
doc.xpath('//div[@id="someID"]') # and this won't work either
```

I don't know what went wrong here,I double checked the HTML source,There are plenty of img tag which contains the attribute(class="productImage").

It's like the attribute selector just won't work.

Here is the URL which the HTML source come from.

```
http://www.amazon.cn/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_1?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%E4%B8%93%E5%85%AB&x=0&y=0&sprefix=%E4%B8%93
```

please do me a favor if you got some spare time.Parse the HTML content like I do see if you can solve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird thing is if you use `open-uri` on that page you get a different result than when using something like `curl` or `wget`.

However when you change the `User-Agent` you actually get probably the page you are looking for:

**Analysis**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'  

URL = 'http://www.amazon.cn/...'

def analyze_html(file)
   doc = Nokogiri.HTML(file)
   pp   doc.xpath('//img').map { |i| i[:class] }.compact.reject(&:empty?)
   puts doc.xpath('//div').map { |i| i[:class] }.grep(/productImage/).count
   puts doc.xpath('//div[@class="productImage"]//img').count
   pp   doc.xpath('//div[@class="productImage"]//img').map { |i| i[:src] }
end

puts "Attempt 1:"
analyze_html(open(URL))

puts "Attempt 2:"
analyze_html(open(URL, "User-Agent" => "Wget/1.10.2"))
```

**Output**:

```
Attempt 1:
["default navSprite"]
0
0
[]
Attempt 2:
["default navSprite", "srSprite spr_kindOfSortBtn"]
16
16
["http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fOb3ujSjL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/513UQ1xiaSL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zKxWXb8HL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bj6XXAouL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/516GBhDTGCL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51ADd3HSE6L._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51CbB-7kotL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2Bw40Mk51L._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/519Gny1LckL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Dv6DUF-WL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51uuy8yHeoL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51T0KEjznqL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/419WTi%2BdjzL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QTg4ZmMmL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51l--Pxw9TL._AA115_.jpg",
 "http://ec4.images-amazon.com/images/I/51gehW2qUZL._AA115_.jpg"]
```

**Solution**:

1. Use `User-Agent: Wget/1.10.2`
2. Use `xpath('//div[@class="productImage"]//img')`

Comment: I am using firebug to analyse the DOM.How could I the the same DOM structure page which is  the page I saw from the firebug(or Firefox).I tried to set the User-Agent to Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.But it seems doesn't work,I think I still get the page that differs from the page which I saw in the Firefox browser.

Comment: @castiel - Hmm. Yes you might be getting a different page. The page is full of Javascript magic, and in fact on my machine with `wget -S -O page your_amz_url` it seems to redirect with a 302 to this page: http://www.amazon.cn/s?ie=UTF8&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A%E4%B8%93%E5%85%AB&page=1 . I suspect you would really need to carefully analyze the whole page and the Javascript in it to fully know what is happening.

Comment: yeah,I think you're right.Anyway, do you know any gem or method that could prettify the HTML source code for me?

Comment: I was stupid,I save the page that fetched by open-uri without specify the User-Agent and use Firebug to analyse the file that I saved.Oh my,it's a completely different page with different DOM structure that full of table,td,tr.That the reason why my original code won't work because there is no div(the div I want) whatsoever.Now I rewrite the xPath expression according to the right page that I got.da-la,everything is working properly now.Thanks for enlighten me,@Casper